# Is it possible to import all contents of cacerts into a jssecacerts file?

Tags: java, keystore

Using keytool , or some other method,  is there an easy way to import all contents of cacerts into a jssecacerts file?

Basically, I want to define my own jssecacerts but I want that jssecacerts to also contain all the trusted entries of the cacerts file.   The reason for this is that I believe that when the jssecacerts file exists, the cacerts file contents are ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
%JRE_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe -importkeystore -destkeystore jssecacerts 
-deststoretype jks -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit 
-v -noprompt -srckeystore %JRE_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts
```