# Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SunJCE_b

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I develop an Java app that is accessing an ssl web service.

I use java 6 jax-ws with basic authentication for accesing this ws.

I configured my local machine (windows) to query this web service.

From certificates point of view I set 2 keystores :    an client keystore that contains an 2 entries : one for my private key and 
                                                  one for my certificate , signed by an CA. The other keystore , the truststore , hold an entry for my app server (that guest the ws) .

This is a self signed certificate and, of course, my client is complaining about this.  I found [here](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) a workaround for this error and I imported this certificate in my truststore.  Now I can query the ws from my local machine.

On PreProduction machine (RHEL 5)  I get the same error message "

> PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target"

I tried to do the same thing.  But when I run:

```
java InstallCert my_ip:ssl_port changeit
```

I get the following output

```
Loading KeyStore cacerts...
Opening connection to my_ip:ssl_port...
Starting SSL handshake...

Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SunJCE_b
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.a(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(JsseJce.java:223)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:91)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:744)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:238)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
        at InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:58)
```

Class javax.crypto.sunJCE_b there is an jce.jar from the jre/lib. What do you think?

Another question: my truststore that I get in windows (the one that contain the imported server certificate) is not portable?

The one that I used on windows, I can copy it on linux, isn't it?

Comment: Hello all of you, 
I tried to get a self signed certificate and load it in my trust store - for this purpose I used InstallCert 
The admin of web server that host the ws told me that I should disable verification self signed certificate and treat it as being trusted . How can I did this disable of verification? In my code I have access to this objects :  oracle.adf.share.ADFContext and oracle.adf.share.security.providers.jps.JpsSecurityContext;
Thanks, 
Aurel

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the jar exists, you might need to **add it to your classpath**, like so:

```
java -cp /path/to/jce.jar:. InstallCert my_ip:ssl_port changeit
```

To only list the classpath, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541055/1587329.

As to

> Another question: my truststore that I get in windows (the one that contain the imported server certificate) is not portable?
>
> The one that I used on windows , I can copy it on linux , isn't it?

It is advised to recreate it: [Migrating a certificate keystore to another JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346042/migrating-a-certificate-keystore-to-another-jvm)

Comment: jce.jar should be added to classpath by default - it is inside jre. Anyway , I tried and this version , I added -cp .... without result

Comment: @aurel: the jar was not even on my system (linux). You can show the contents of a jar via `jar xf filename` Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes , I tried , the class about java complains is there , in jce.jar

Answer (score 0):

i faced a similar problem working with installCert application. Try modifiying the Java Crypto Policys. Download the files from oracle, [JCE for Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html).

You just download and replace the existing files in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security.
That should work.

Comment: Your default truststore is "cacerts" file on the same folder. Just copy it and paste it on your JVM on linux.

Comment: Thanks , but I'm working with java 6 , you want to say jce for java 6 , isn't it? I did this -with jars for java 6, with no positive results

Comment: ops, true. You should download the jce java 6 from oracle : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html